# Open in new window or tab

Tags: javascript, winforms, parent-child, parent

I would like to open the following in a new window or tab.  Currently it opens in the same window so that after sending the email, the page must be reloaded. This is a part of [this webpage](http://www.midaslink.com/maxencode.htm)

```
function email_message()
{
   bodytext = document.getElementById("end").value;

   if (bodytext.length > 1850)
   {
      alert("Oops!  The E-Mail Someone button can only be used for short messages, 3 or    less lines of message text.  \nYou can always copy the Encoded Message and past into your regular email!")
      return;
   }
   who_to = prompt("Enter recipient's email address: ","anybody@anywhere.com");
   s_line = "Encoded Message";

   var confirm_send = confirm("Send Email?");
   if (confirm_send == true)
   {
      parent.location.href = 'mailto:' + who_to + '?subject=' + s_line + '&body=' + "Decode at www.mysite.com/myhtml.htm%0D%0D" + bodytext;
   }
   else
   {
   return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.open()` instead of `location.href = `? Or...wait, why is a `mailto:` link opening in the browser at all? Do you have your browser configured for a webmail service, or...?

Comment: Also, for ppl that have email cilents installed like Outlook, it will open in an Outlook.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: You haven't tried Google "javascript open new tab" , please atleast attempt to search for an answer before posting question

Comment: The user's default email opens in the same page if the default browser is used to view the webpage.  If a non-default browser is used, the email opens in the normal default browser, which is fine.  Was not aware of "javascript open new tab", but will search dor such.  Thanks

Comment: @Rellif:try window.open(url, '_blank');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.open`

You just needs this bit of code below to open the page in a new window,Have tried this

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```